# Solutions to an elliptic curve equation involving a prime

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a prime and let $x$ be a positive integer. How do I prove that the equation
$$y^2=px^3+p$$
has infinitely many integer solutions? I tried to tackle this problem using elliptic curves and other similar computational techniques but unfortunately, it didn't get me anywhere satisfactory.

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I imagine you allow $p$ to vary? For any fixed $p$, there will only be finitely many solutions by Siegel's theorem.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $x$ a positive integer, then $y^2 = px^3 + p$ has at most two solutions.